# Passing char array to CUDA Kernel

Tags: c++, c, cuda, arrays

I am trying to pass an char array containing 10000 words read from a txt file in the main function to CUDA kernel function.

The words are transferred from the host to device like this:

(main function code:)

```
//.....
     const int text_length = 20;

     char (*wordList)[text_length] = new char[10000][text_length];
     char *dev_wordList;

     for(int i=0; i<number_of_words; i++)
     {
         file>>wordList[i];
         cout<<wordList[i]<<endl;
     }

     cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_wordList, 20*number_of_words*sizeof(char));
     cudaMemcpy(dev_wordList, &(wordList[0][0]), 20 * number_of_words * sizeof(char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    //Setup execution parameters
    int n_blocks = (number_of_words + 255)/256;
    int threads_per_block = 256;


    dim3 grid(n_blocks, 1, 1);
    dim3 threads(threads_per_block, 1, 1);


    cudaPrintfInit();
    testKernel<<<grid, threads>>>(dev_wordList);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaPrintfDisplay(stdout,true);
    cudaPrintfEnd();
```

(kernel function code:)

```
__global__ void testKernel(char* d_wordList)
{
    //access thread id
    const unsigned int bid = blockIdx.x;
    const unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
    const unsigned int index = bid * blockDim.x + tid;

    cuPrintf("!! %c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c \n" , d_wordList[index * 20 + 0],
                                            d_wordList[index * 20 + 1],
                                            d_wordList[index * 20 + 2],
                                            d_wordList[index * 20 + 3],
                                            d_wordList[index * 20 + 4],
                                            d_wordList[index * 20 + 5],
                                            d_wordList[index * 20 + 6],
                                            d_wordList[index * 20 + 7],
                                            d_wordList[index * 20 + 8],
                                            d_wordList[index * 20 + 9]);
}
```

Is there a way to manipulate them easier? (I would like to have a word per element/position) I tried with `<string>`, but I can't use them in CUDA device code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cuPrintf("%s\n", d_wordlist+(index*20));
```

should work? (provided your strings are zero-terminated)

Update:

This line:

```
char (*wordList)[text_length] = new char[10000][text_length];
```

looks strange to me. In general, array of pointers to char would be allocated like this:

```
char** wordList = new char*[10000];
for (int i=0;i<10000;i++) wordList[i] = new char[20];
```

In this case, wordList[i]  would be a pointer to string number i.

Update #2:

If you need to store your strings as a consecutive block, and you are sure that none of your strings exceeds text_length+1, then you can do like that:

```
char *wordList = new char[10000*text_length];

for(int i=0; i<number_of_words; i++)
     {
         file>>wordList+(i*text_length);
         cout<<wordList+(i*text_length)<<endl;
     }
```

In that case, wordList + (i*text_length) will point to the beginning of your string number i, and it will be 0-terminated because that's how you read it from the file, and you will be able to print it out with the way specified in this answer. If any of your strings is longer than text_length-1, however, you will still get issues.

Comment: I tried but I get a sequence of strange characters.

Comment: The way you copy your strings in the code, it looks like they are not zero-terminated (you allocate 20 symbols per string and do memcpy i/o strcpy). Would it be possible to allocate 21 symbol per string and add '\0' after each string?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure how to do it. It would be better if the terminator would be after each string.

Comment: are all your words 20 symbols or you just estimate them to be so?

Comment: I just estimate them to be so. It wold be better if I wouldn't have spaces after strings. Maybe I'm not reading from file correctliy.

Comment: this line: `char (*wordList)[text_length] = new char[10000][text_length];` seems strange, you don't generally allocate array of pointers this way.

Comment: I tried with this form:  char *wordList[10000];
  for(i=0;i<10000;i++)
  {
    wordList[i]=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
  }
 But it doesn't work.

Comment: What does not work? If you mean that then you don't get a consecutive space where you put your strings, then indeed, you won't.

Comment: No, when I compile the program, VS generates a window with the message "<Name of the project>" has stopped working.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I used the sequence of code listed in #update 2, and also modified the line with de transfer of the char array from host to device  cudaMemcpy(dev_wordList, wordList, 20 * number_of_words * sizeof(char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); but the program still outputs the strange characters.

Comment: The transfer of strings from host to device is correct, the problem is with the cuPrintf call, I tried to output a string declared in the kernel function and it only outputs the string if it's declared as const char*.  So I modified the kernel function parameter declaration from __global__ void testKernel(char* d_wordList) to __global__ void testKernel(**const** char* d_wordList) and now it work's. Thanks a lot!